# A verb meaning "to make fail"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs

1. > That view fails to qualify as scientific because it is biased.
2. > The fact that it is biased fails that view to qualify as scientific.

Are both usages of "fail" in 1 and 2 correct? If not, how could 2 be said?

Answer (score 3):

Two other ways of saying this, the second uses the word "disqualifies" as a verb that means what you want it to mean.

"Because that view is biased, it fails to qualify as scientific."

"The fact that the view is biased disqualifies it as scientific."

Answer (score 2):

No, **fail** cannot be used in example two. Instead, try this:

The fact that it is biased *[precludes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/preclude)* that view from qualifying as scientific.

> Prevent from happening; make impossible.